# Appium-Java : Getting "session could not be created "error while executing below android app automation code

Tags: java, android, selenium

```
package eexample.com;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;
import io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver;
import io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver;
import io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidElement;
import io.appium.java_client.remote.MobileCapabilityType;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities;
import org.testng.Assert;
import org.testng.annotations.AfterClass;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeClass;

public class NewTest {
  AppiumDriver<AndroidElement> driver;
  @BeforeClass
  public void f() throws MalformedURLException { 
      DesiredCapabilities cap = new DesiredCapabilities();
      cap.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.DEVICE_NAME, "Le X507");
      cap.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.APPIUM_VERSION, "6.0");
      cap.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.NEW_COMMAND_TIMEOUT, "4000");
      cap.setCapability("appPackage", "urdoorstep.com");
      cap.setCapability("appActivity", "com.martjack.urdoorstep.SplashScreen");       
      cap.setCapability("appWaitActivity", "com.martjack.urdoorstep.LoginTabbedPage");

      driver =new AndroidDriver<AndroidElement>(new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub"),cap);    
  } 

  @Test
  public void testcase1()throws Exception {
     driver.findElementById("urdoorstep.com:id/loginbutton").click();          
 Assert.assertTrue(driver.findElementById("urdoorstep.com:id/loginbutton").isDisplayed());
  }

  @AfterClass
  public void testCaseTearDown() {
    driver.quit();
  }
}
```

getting below error:

> info: --> POST /wd/hub/session {"desiredCapabilities":{"appPackage":"urdoorstep.com","appActivity":"com.martjack.urdoorstep.SplashScreen","appWaitActivity":"com.martjack.urdoorstep.LoginTabbedPage","platformName":"Android","deviceName":"Le X507","platform":"ANDROID"}}
>   info: Client User-Agent string: Apache-HttpClient/4.5.1 (Java/1.8.0_101)
>   info: [debug] The following desired capabilities were provided, but not recognized by appium. They will be passed on to any other services running on this server. : platform
>   info: [debug] Didn't get app but did get Android package, will attempt to launch it on the device
>   info: [debug] Creating new appium session 4837f17e-d35e-43cc-9ffb-2a85f3de2c16
>   info: Starting android appium
>   info: [debug] Getting Java version
>   info: Java version is: 1.8.0_101
>   info: [debug] Checking whether adb is present
>   info: [debug] Using adb from D:\Ashok_Automation_New\sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe
>   warn: No app capability, can't parse package/activity
>   info: [debug] Using fast reset? true
>   info: [debug] Preparing device for session
>   info: [debug] Not checking whether app is present since we are assuming it's already on the device
>   info: Retrieving device
>   info: [debug] Trying to find a connected android device
>   info: [debug] Getting connected devices...
>   info: [debug] executing cmd: D:\Ashok_Automation_New\sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe devices
>   info: [debug] 1 device(s) connected
>   info: Found device EELVL7INM7SWHYSG
>   info: [debug] Setting device id to EELVL7INM7SWHYSG
>   info: [debug] Waiting for device to be ready and to respond to shell commands (timeout = 5)
>   info: [debug] executing cmd: D:\Ashok_Automation_New\sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe -s EELVL7INM7SWHYSG wait-for-device
>   info: [debug] executing cmd: D:\Ashok_Automation_New\sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe -s EELVL7INM7SWHYSG shell "echo 'ready'"
>   info: [debug] Starting logcat capture
>   info: [debug] Getting device API level
>   info: [debug] executing cmd: D:\Ashok_Automation_New\sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe -s EELVL7INM7SWHYSG shell "getprop ro.build.version.sdk"
>   info: [debug] Device is at API Level 23
>   info: Device API level is: 23
>   info: [debug] Extracting strings for language: default
>   info: [debug] Apk doesn't exist locally
>   info: [debug] Could not get strings, but it looks like we had an old strings file anyway, so ignoring
>   info: [debug] executing cmd: D:\Ashok_Automation_New\sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe -s EELVL7INM7SWHYSG shell "rm -rf /data/local/tmp/strings.json"
>   info: [debug] Not uninstalling app since server not started with --full-reset
>   info: [debug] Skipping install since we launched with a package instead of an app path
>   info: [debug] Forwarding system:4724 to device:4724
>   info: [debug] executing cmd: D:\Ashok_Automation_New\sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe -s EELVL7INM7SWHYSG forward tcp:4724 tcp:4724
>   info: [debug] Pushing appium bootstrap to device...
>   info: [debug] executing cmd: D:\Ashok_Automation_New\sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe -s EELVL7INM7SWHYSG push "C:\Program Files (x86)\Appium\node_modules\appium\build\android_bootstrap\AppiumBootstrap.jar" /data/local/tmp/
>   info: [debug] Pushing settings apk to device...
>   info: [debug] executing cmd: D:\Ashok_Automation_New\sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe -s EELVL7INM7SWHYSG install "C:\Program Files (x86)\Appium\node_modules\appium\build\settings_apk\settings_apk-debug.apk"
>   info: [debug] Pushing unlock helper app to device...
>   info: [debug] executing cmd: D:\Ashok_Automation_New\sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe -s EELVL7INM7SWHYSG install "C:\Program Files (x86)\Appium\node_modules\appium\build\unlock_apk\unlock_apk-debug.apk"
>   info: Starting App
>   info: [debug] Attempting to kill all 'uiautomator' processes
>   info: [debug] Getting all processes with 'uiautomator'
>   info: [debug] executing cmd: D:\Ashok_Automation_New\sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe -s EELVL7INM7SWHYSG shell "ps 'uiautomator'"
>   info: [debug] No matching processes found
>   info: [debug] Running bootstrap
>   info: [debug] spawning: D:\Ashok_Automation_New\sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe -s EELVL7INM7SWHYSG shell uiautomator runtest AppiumBootstrap.jar -c io.appium.android.bootstrap.Bootstrap -e pkg urdoorstep.com -e disableAndroidWatchers false
>   info: [debug] [UIAUTOMATOR STDOUT] INSTRUMENTATION_STATUS: numtests=1
>   info: [debug] [UIAUTOMATOR STDOUT] INSTRUMENTATION_STATUS: stream=
>   info: [debug] [UIAUTOMATOR STDOUT] io.appium.android.bootstrap.Bootstrap:
>   info: [debug] [UIAUTOMATOR STDOUT] INSTRUMENTATION_STATUS: id=UiAutomatorTestRunner
>   info: [debug] [UIAUTOMATOR STDOUT] INSTRUMENTATION_STATUS: test=testRunServer
>   info: [debug] [UIAUTOMATOR STDOUT] INSTRUMENTATION_STATUS: class=io.appium.android.bootstrap.Bootstrap
>   info: [debug] [UIAUTOMATOR STDOUT] INSTRUMENTATION_STATUS: current=1
>   info: [debug] [UIAUTOMATOR STDOUT] INSTRUMENTATION_STATUS_CODE: 1
>   info: [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Socket opened on port 4724
>   info: [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Appium Socket Server Ready
>   info: [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Loading json...
>   info: [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Registered crash watchers.
>   info: [debug] Waking up device if it's not alive
>   info: [debug] Pushing command to appium work queue: ["wake",{}]
>   info: [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Client connected
>   info: [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Got data from client: {"cmd":"action","action":"wake","params":{}}
>   info: [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Got command of type ACTION
>   info: [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Got command action: wake
>   info: [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Returning result: {"status":0,"value":true}
>   info: [debug] executing cmd: D:\Ashok_Automation_New\sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe -s EELVL7INM7SWHYSG shell "dumpsys window"
>   info: [debug] Screen already unlocked, continuing.
>   info: [debug] Pushing command to appium work queue: ["getDataDir",{}]
>   info: [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Got data from client: {"cmd":"action","action":"getDataDir","params":{}}
>   info: [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Got command of type ACTION
>   info: [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Got command action: getDataDir
>   info: [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Returning result: {"status":0,"value":"/data/local/tmp"}
>   info: [debug] dataDir set to: /data/local/tmp
>   info: [debug] Pushing command to appium work queue: ["compressedLayoutHierarchy",{"compressLayout":false}]
>   info: [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Got data from client: {"cmd":"action","action":"compressedLayoutHierarchy","params":{"compressLayout":false}}
>   info: [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Got command of type ACTION
>   info: [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Got command action: compressedLayoutHierarchy
>   info: [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Returning result: {"status":0,"value":false}
>   info: [debug] Getting device API level
>   info: [debug] executing cmd: D:\Ashok_Automation_New\sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe -s EELVL7INM7SWHYSG shell "getprop ro.build.version.sdk"
>   info: [debug] Device is at API Level 23
>   info: [debug] executing cmd: D:\Ashok_Automation_New\sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe -s EELVL7INM7SWHYSG shell "am start -S -a android.intent.action.MAIN -c android.intent.category.LAUNCHER -f 0x10200000 -n urdoorstep.com/com.martjack.urdoorstep.SplashScreen"
>   info: [debug] Waiting for pkg "urdoorstep.com" and activity "com.martjack.urdoorstep.LoginTabbedPage" to be focused
>   info: [debug] Getting focused package and activity
>   info: [debug] executing cmd: D:\Ashok_Automation_New\sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe -s EELVL7INM7SWHYSG shell "dumpsys window windows"
>   info: [debug] Getting focused package and activity
>   info: [debug] executing cmd: D:\Ashok_Automation_New\sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe -s EELVL7INM7SWHYSG shell "dumpsys window windows"
>   info: [debug] Getting focused package and activity
>   info: [debug] executing cmd: D:\Ashok_Automation_New\sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe -s EELVL7INM7SWHYSG shell "dumpsys window windows"
>   info: [debug] Getting focused package and activity
>   info: [debug] executing cmd: D:\Ashok_Automation_New\sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe -s EELVL7INM7SWHYSG shell "dumpsys window windows"
>   info: [debug] Getting focused package and activity
>   info: [debug] executing cmd: D:\Ashok_Automation_New\sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe -s EELVL7INM7SWHYSG shell "dumpsys window windows"
>   info: [debug] Getting focused package and activity
>   info: [debug] executing cmd: D:\Ashok_Automation_New\sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe -s EELVL7INM7SWHYSG shell "dumpsys window windows"
>   info: [debug] Getting focused package and activity
>   info: [debug] executing cmd: D:\Ashok_Automation_New\sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe -s EELVL7INM7SWHYSG shell "dumpsys window windows"
>   info: [debug] Getting focused package and activity
>   info: [debug] executing cmd: D:\Ashok_Automation_New\sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe -s EELVL7INM7SWHYSG shell "dumpsys window windows"
>   info: [debug] Getting focused package and activity
>   info: [debug] executing cmd: D:\Ashok_Automation_New\sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe -s EELVL7INM7SWHYSG shell "dumpsys window windows"
>   info: [debug] Getting focused package and activity
>   info: [debug] executing cmd: D:\Ashok_Automation_New\sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe -s EELVL7INM7SWHYSG shell "dumpsys window windows"
>   info: [debug] Getting focused package and activity
>   info: [debug] executing cmd: D:\Ashok_Automation_New\sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe -s EELVL7INM7SWHYSG shell "dumpsys window windows"
>   info: [debug] Getting focused package and activity
>   info: [debug] executing cmd: D:\Ashok_Automation_New\sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe -s EELVL7INM7SWHYSG shell "dumpsys window windows"
>   info: [debug] Getting focused package and activity
>   info: [debug] executing cmd: D:\Ashok_Automation_New\sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe -s EELVL7INM7SWHYSG shell "dumpsys window windows"
>   info: [debug] Getting focused package and activity
>   info: [debug] executing cmd: D:\Ashok_Automation_New\sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe -s EELVL7INM7SWHYSG shell "dumpsys window windows"
>   info: [debug] Getting focused package and activity
>   info: [debug] executing cmd: D:\Ashok_Automation_New\sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe -s EELVL7INM7SWHYSG shell "dumpsys window windows"
>   info: [debug] Getting focused package and activity
>   info: [debug] executing cmd: D:\Ashok_Automation_New\sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe -s EELVL7INM7SWHYSG shell "dumpsys window windows"
>   info: [debug] Getting focused package and activity
>   info: [debug] executing cmd: D:\Ashok_Automation_New\sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe -s EELVL7INM7SWHYSG shell "dumpsys window windows"
>   info: [debug] Getting focused package and activity
>   info: [debug] executing cmd: D:\Ashok_Automation_New\sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe -s EELVL7INM7SWHYSG shell "dumpsys window windows"
>   info: [debug] Getting focused package and activity
>   info: [debug] executing cmd: D:\Ashok_Automation_New\sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe -s EELVL7INM7SWHYSG shell "dumpsys window windows"
>   info: [debug] Getting focused package and activity
>   info: [debug] executing cmd: D:\Ashok_Automation_New\sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe -s EELVL7INM7SWHYSG shell "dumpsys window windows"
>   info: [debug] Getting focused package and activity
>   info: [debug] executing cmd: D:\Ashok_Automation_New\sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe -s EELVL7INM7SWHYSG shell "dumpsys window windows"
>   info: [debug] Getting focused package and activity
>   info: [debug] executing cmd: D:\Ashok_Automation_New\sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe -s EELVL7INM7SWHYSG shell "dumpsys window windows"
>   info: [debug] Getting focused package and activity
>   info: [debug] executing cmd: D:\Ashok_Automation_New\sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe -s EELVL7INM7SWHYSG shell "dumpsys window windows"
>   info: [debug] Getting focused package and activity
>   info: [debug] executing cmd: D:\Ashok_Automation_New\sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe -s EELVL7INM7SWHYSG shell "dumpsys window windows"
>   info: [debug] Getting focused package and activity
>   info: [debug] executing cmd: D:\Ashok_Automation_New\sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe -s EELVL7INM7SWHYSG shell "dumpsys window windows"
>   error: urdoorstep.com/com.martjack.urdoorstep.LoginTabbedPage never started. Current: urdoorstep.com/com.martjack.urdoorstep.LoginTabbedPage,
>   info: [debug] Stopping logcat capture
>   info: [debug] Logcat terminated with code null, signal SIGTERM
>   info: [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Got data from client: {"cmd":"shutdown"}
>   info: [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Got command of type SHUTDOWN
>   info: [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Returning result: {"status":0,"value":"OK, shutting down"}
>   info: [debug] [UIAUTOMATOR STDOUT] close [socket][/127.0.0.1:4724]
>   info: [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Closed client connection
>   info: [debug] [UIAUTOMATOR STDOUT] INSTRUMENTATION_STATUS: numtests=1
>   info: [debug] [UIAUTOMATOR STDOUT] INSTRUMENTATION_STATUS: stream=.
>   info: [debug] [UIAUTOMATOR STDOUT] INSTRUMENTATION_STATUS: id=UiAutomatorTestRunner
>   info: [debug] [UIAUTOMATOR STDOUT] INSTRUMENTATION_STATUS: test=testRunServer
>   info: [debug] [UIAUTOMATOR STDOUT] INSTRUMENTATION_STATUS: class=io.appium.android.bootstrap.Bootstrap
>   info: [debug] [UIAUTOMATOR STDOUT] INSTRUMENTATION_STATUS: current=1
>   info: [debug] [UIAUTOMATOR STDOUT] INSTRUMENTATION_STATUS_CODE: 0
>   info: [debug] [UIAUTOMATOR STDOUT] INSTRUMENTATION_STATUS: stream=
>   info: [debug] [UIAUTOMATOR STDOUT] Test results for WatcherResultPrinter=.
>   info: [debug] [UIAUTOMATOR STDOUT] Time: 21.94
>   info: [debug] [UIAUTOMATOR STDOUT] OK (1 test)
>   info: [debug] [UIAUTOMATOR STDOUT] INSTRUMENTATION_STATUS_CODE: -1
>   info: [debug] Sent shutdown command, waiting for UiAutomator to stop...
>   info: [debug] UiAutomator shut down normally
>   info: [debug] Cleaning up android objects
>   info: [debug] Cleaning up appium session
>   error: Failed to start an Appium session, err was: Error: urdoorstep.com/com.martjack.urdoorstep.LoginTabbedPage never started. Current: urdoorstep.com/com.martjack.urdoorstep.LoginTabbedPage,
>   info: [debug] Error: urdoorstep.com/com.martjack.urdoorstep.LoginTabbedPage never started. Current: urdoorstep.com/com.martjack.urdoorstep.LoginTabbedPage,
>       at [object Object]. (C:\Program Files (x86)\Appium\node_modules\appium\node_modules\appium-adb\lib\adb.js:1314:12)
>       at [object Object]. (C:\Program Files (x86)\Appium\node_modules\appium\node_modules\appium-adb\lib\adb.js:1258:7)
>       at [object Object]. (C:\Program Files (x86)\Appium\node_modules\appium\node_modules\appium-adb\lib\adb.js:180:9)
>       at ChildProcess.exithandler (child_process.js:742:7)
>       at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:110:17)
>       at maybeClose (child_process.js:1016:16)
>       at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:1088:5)
>   info: [debug] Responding to client with error: {"status":33,"value":{"message":"A new session could not be created. (Original error: urdoorstep.com/com.martjack.urdoorstep.LoginTabbedPage never started. Current: urdoorstep.com/com.martjack.urdoorstep.LoginTabbedPage,)","origValue":"urdoorstep.com/com.martjack.urdoorstep.LoginTabbedPage never started. Current: urdoorstep.com/com.martjack.urdoorstep.LoginTabbedPage,"},"sessionId":null}
>   info: <-- POST /wd/hub/session 500 27272.938 ms - 390

Comment: your package name different and your activity name is different use this for "appWaitActiviity" is "urdoorstep.com/com.martjack.urdoorstep.LoginTabbedPage" and you need to check start activity also

Comment: Thanks for reply.Activity launching properly..Same working in C# properly..but in java facing this issue.Package and activities are fine.

Comment: Try This and let me know if app launches.((AndroidDriver)driver).startActivity("com.martjack.urdoorstep.SplashScreen");

Comment: Not working.Nullpointer exception error came